# Can we do zoom-in and zoom-out while video is live streaming? by using raspberry pi camera?

Tags: pi-3

Can I do zoom-in and zoom-out, while live streaming the video using the raspberry pi camera? Is there any python code to do so? I am unable to zoom the video while live streaming. Please help me with the issue.

Comment: PiCamera doesn't have motorized. The answer is NO.